# when the spinner is clicked, it says " Showing 2 items" while displaying dropdown view. How to override this talkback for spinner?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback, accessibilityservice

while I implement Spinner for creating dropdown view, the first element is always shown in main view as well as in dropdown list. **so I hid it by overriding getDropdrownView().** but problem arises in talkback.

Problem is: when I click on spinner, it opens up dropdown view and says "**showing 2 items**" even if 1 item is present there. I wanted to override the Read out text as "**showing 1 item**"  by providing onclickListener . But spinner doesnt support click events.

I tried ontouchListener, onkeyListener but nothing could override the text "Showing 2 items".
**setContentDescription** also not working.
I tried the following but it did not work too:

```
AccessibilityEvent talkBackEvent = AccessibilityEvent.obtain(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);
talkBackEvent.getText().add("showing 1 item");
mSelectSpinner.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(talkBackEvent);
mSelectSpinner.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(talkBackEvent);
mSelectSpinner.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(talkBackEvent);
```

Please help me out ..there is very less forum discussions we find about talkback.

Comment: It sounds like your spinner is actually showing two items, though? Overriding this speech would be inaccurate.

Comment: Yes.. You are right... I have two items in the spinner .. But i am making visibility of 1st item as GONE. will it be possible to remove1st item in the spinner ? I think in that case spinner would work right...

Comment: This is a bug in ListView's reporting of item count -- it's not taking into account view visibility. You can technically fix this from your app, but it might interfere with TalkBack's list traversal and it would break again when the bug in ListView is fixed in a future release. Could you file a bug at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is addressed in subsequent versions of android.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.